# lxml how to append a new element and its value to node?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml

I have an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 - <note>
       <to>Tove</to>
       <from>Jani</from>
       <heading>Reminder</heading>
       <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
   </note>
```

Now I want to add an id element and its value under the note,the out put should looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 - <note>
       <id>3</id>
       <to>Tove</to>
       <from>Jani</from>
       <heading>Reminder</heading>
       <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
   </note>
```

Any friends can help?

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Did you check if there is `insert()` ? Did you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: do you have `-` before `<note>` ? It may be incorrect XML and `lxml` has problem to read it.

Answer (score 0):

If you would have xml without `-` then it would be valid xml and it would work with `lxml`

You can create new element using `Element()`

```
import lxml.etree as ET

item = ET.Element('id')
item.text = '3'
item.tail = '\n       '  # to format indentation
```

and then you can use `element.insert(position, new_element)`

```
tree = ET.fromstring(text.encode('utf-8'))

note = tree
#note = tree.find('note')

note.insert(0, item)
```

---

Minimal working code (without `-`)

```
text = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
       <to>Tove</to>
       <from>Jani</from>
       <heading>Reminder</heading>
       <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
'''

import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.fromstring(text.encode('utf-8'))

note = tree
#note = tree.find('note')

item = ET.Element('id')
item.text = '3'
item.tail = '\n       '

note.insert(0, item)

text = ET.tostring(tree, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8').decode()

print(text)
```

Result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<note>
       <id>3</id>
       <to>Tove</to>
       <from>Jani</from>
       <heading>Reminder</heading>
       <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```